# Error when accessing Core Service from a client machine

Tags: tridion

I am working with the Core Service on SDL Tridion 2011, connecting from client machine to the Tridion server. I am getting some error while I am trying to execeute it.

Sample code

```
namespace coreservice1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService> factory =  new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>("wsHttp_2011"))
                {

                    ISessionAwareCoreService client = factory.CreateChannel();
                    ComponentData comp = (ComponentData)client.Create(component, new ReadOptions());

                    ...

                    //steps to create component                

               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
                Response.Write("exception is " + ex.Message);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

My web.config for the wsHttp_2011 is

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttp" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760"/>
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>


<endpoint name="wsHttp_2011" address="http://serveraddress:1000/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService">
    <identity>
        <dns value="serveraddress"/>
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
________________________________________
Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Logging' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
```

My client code is referrring to Tridion.Logging. This assembly exists in my code. Irrespective of its existence I am getting the error. And the versions of DLL that I am referring in the client code are exactly same as in the server.

Can any one help, what all the changes I need to do?

I also checked the event logs in tridion server. I didn't find any log added there.

The code was working fine when executed on the server machine.

Event Viewer logs are like this from client machine:

> ConfigurationErrorsException
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Logging, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified. The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Logging, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified. The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Logging' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified. The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
>     at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

I didn't find any event in the log on the server.

Comment: Exception you see, is it on client on server side? Do you see anything in the event log? Can you specify what operating system and architecture are you using? Are you using service reference, or CoreService.dll? Is your client on the same machine as server?

Comment: I am using Coreservice.dll. My client is not same as server. Its different.

Comment: using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: Does your client code reference Tridion.Logging? Does the assembly exist on the client machine?

Comment: And are the versions of the DLLs you are referencing in the client code exactly the same as those on the server?

Comment: Also, by heart I think on SDL Tridion 2011 GA, the Tridion.Logging.dll was only available in the GAC. So you would need to copy that manually to your client to be able to reference it, but the big question is if you really should be doing that at all in this case (this code should not reference or require Tridion logging at all)

Comment: My client code is referrring to Tridion.Logging. This assembly exists in my code. Irrespective of its existence i am getting the error. And the versions of DLL that i am referring in the client code are excatly same as in the server.

Answer (score 4):

You should not reference Tridion.Logging. It's not required for CoreService. All you need is CoreService.dll. Moreover, Tridion.Logging is not public API and thus shouldn't be used at all

Comment: Make sure that the only Tridion assembly you are referencing is CoreService.dll

Comment: The error is not that Tridion.Logging is missing, it's that "one of its dependencies" is missing - namely Tridion. As user978511 says, make sure you only use the CoreService client dll.

Comment: No Luck. Even after removing the dlls except CoreService client dll, i am facing same error.

Comment: @muzimil Is it server side error? Can you see anything in the Tridion or Tridion Content Manager event logs on server?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Tridion event log. Also make sure you are not using any other Tridion assemblies.